# django form is_valid and cleaned_data to achieve Save and Submit behavior.

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I m working with formset, and trying to implement save option.
ie: You enter form details in the form page, have two functionalities

1) Save

2) Submit

For Save -> I would like to save the data into database without validation.[ irrespective of the case if the user entered for required field]

For Submit -> Ofcourse with the Validation and saving into database.

For Submit , i have no issues.

But for Save:

```
 for form in formset.form:
     1) Validate the form form.is_validate() -> Just invoking.
     2) get the cleaned_data
```

In the below approach,

1) does cleaned_data available only if is_valid() is True ?

2) Do we have any other approach to achieve the same?

Your help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

> 1) does cleaned_data available only if is_valid() is True ?

Yes. Its available only when form is valid.

> 2) Do we have any other approach to achieve the same?

I don't think you can save such data in DB in same table. However, you can save that in session (cookies). You can serialize the form (or submitted POST data) and save it as JSON in session.

To show earlier saved form, you can retrieve this data and pass it as `initial_data` to the form or formset.

Comment: That means storing partial information from the form to db is nightmare?  From the documenation " Changed in Django 1.5.

Django used to remove the cleaned_data attribute entirely if there were any errors in the form. Since version 1.5, cleaned_data is present even if the form doesn’t validate, but it contains only field values that did validate."

Comment: i tried fields.required = False before i save form.save(), but still it throws validation error.

Comment: @Whoami, I missed change in 1.5. However, even if some attributes are present, you may not able to save the object in DB if any required attribute is not there or there is some other error like integrity error etc. Best way is to store such data as JSON in separate table (or session) and use it whenever you want to resume.